# How would a disappearing moon move

Tags: science-based, magic

In the dnd adventure world Ptolus, there is a moon, the vallis moon, that provides the magic to the world.

> *from memory, not quotes*
>
> The story line states that the moon is moving further and further away from the planet, making magic more and more faint.
>
> It also says that the moon returns with periods making some periods more magical and some periods less magical.

This makes me believe that the moon is moving away from the plane, like ours does, but in a much greater speed.

It also makes me believe that the moon in in an elliptical orbit around the planet.

How would the orbit look like for such a moon?

Can it be calculated how it would look like in the future, i'm fishing after maybe a predictable date (year) where the moon would only have it's magical power in range for a short period of time. Like some comets.

There is no specifications as to the size or mass of the world nor the moon, but lets assume that Monte Cook used our earth and moon as inspiration.

I would like to have it tagged as hard science, but it is a magical moon.

Comment: Science-based *and* magic tags?

Comment: It is a magic moon in a magic world. But i want a real world answer.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse (?) OK, “that can’t happen.”

Comment: @PEMapModder i did actually write that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe **is** our moon, magicked up.

[Moon's orbit is elliptical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_of_the_Moon#Elliptic_shape), it really is sometimes closer, sometimes farther from Earth. Apparent diameter changes by 12%, as seen on image from Wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: Except the other moon is moving away faster that than our moon. And that would be the answer i was looking for.

Comment: If you can paste exact quote or make up exact speeds, answer could be more precise. Most moons move away (or closer), and most have elliptical orbits. That's how universe works.

Comment: The earth is also slowly moving away from the sun, if I recall correctly.